# What does this himself mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Who? " 
>        "Well –– I don' like sayin'
>   the name if I can help it. No one does." 
>        "Why
>   not?" 
>        "Gulpin' gargoyles, Harry, people are
>   still scared. Blimey, this is difficult. See, there was this wizard
>   who went... bad. As bad as you could go. Worse. Worse than worse. His
>   name was..." 
>        Hagrid gulped, but no words came
>   out. 
>        "Could you write it down?" Harry suggested.
>   
>        "Nah –– can't spell it. All right –– Voldemort.
>   " Hagrid shuddered. "Don' make me say it again. Anyway, this –– this
>   wizard, about twenty years ago now, started lookin' fer followers. Got
>   'em, too –– some were afraid, some just wanted a bit o' his power,
>   'cause he was gettin' ***himself*** power, all right. Dark days,
>   Harry. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘himself’ [used as the object of the verb](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/oneself)(OALD #1) or used to emphasize him (OALD #2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Himself** is the reflexive form of the object pronoun **him**, and in this case it is the indirect object of "gettin'", with "power" as the direct object:

> He was gettin' power **for himself**.